# Fireworks Animations in Windows 8 Metro App Microsoft Minesweeper

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for specific help to create a Fireworks animation in my own Windows 8 Metro App which will be based on the Fireworks Animation after a game gets successfully completed in the latest "Microsoft Minesweeper" Windows 8 Metro App.

Any ideas, hints, documentation will help.

Comment: How about http://www.javascript-fx.com/submitscripts/fireworks/ ?

Comment: quite interesting. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to create animations in Windows Store XAML apps: 1) Storyboards and 2) Procedural animations.

Storyboards are great for moving UI elements like buttons and listboxes around the screen. You can animate basically any property on the object that you want to change over time. The problem with storyboards is that they're *targeted* at specific elements in the scene, e.g. it will always animate the same button every time you play it. You can read MUCH more about storyboard animations here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721608.aspx

For fireworks and other dynamic animations like particle effects, you really need to use procedural animations. Procedural animations are called procedural because they're generated in code frame-by-frame. This sounds complicated, and it is a bit more tough to come up with than using the timeline feature in Blend, but the results are astounding and you can usually find some good samples online. In fact, here's a great article on procedural animations that includes code for an explosion and for swirling stars. I bet you could some up with something cool based on those two examples.

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/03/advanced-animation-animating-15000-visuals-in-silverlight-2/

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Comment: Or record your animation and play a video.

Comment: Thanks Jared and Jerry. I am setting up a 1 to 1 with generationapp team to get more help with Fireworks animation. Thanks for the comprehensive sum up. I am accepting the answer.

Comment: Awesome. The Generation App guys are great. Let us know if you need more help.